# Using 2 Node.js express server on same machine exposing only one

Tags: node.js, express, server, command-line-interface

I have a backend service for a business application, this service is a Node.js express server that is running on a proprietary machine. (database access, business logic, ...)

I have a second Node.js app that i need to use from my backend server without exposing it. This second service can be used via CLI but also gives me the opportunity to start it as a server an use it via REST API.

What should i do to call the second service from the main service?

I thought about calling the service using the CLI with Node.js child process but i am concerned about security issues, is there a way to start and call the second server from the main one without exposing it?

Comment: A command line application should never be exposed to the outside world.  If it is, that's the least of your problems.  A server can be easily restricted from outside access by just running it on a port that isn't exposed to the outside world (via the firewall, proxy or whatever infrastructure your hosting company is using).  If this is something you are regularly accessing, it is probably more efficient to access it as a server.  Just run that server on a port that isn't exposed to the outside world and then use http requests from your main server to make requests to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will definitely use that as a server and i will ask the server manager to configure the proxy to block requests from outside.